# Assigning IP addresses to eth0

Tags: networking, 20.04, netplan, ip-address, pentesting

I'm totally new to both linux and pentesting. I'm following the HTB academy, but I'm stuck on assigning IP addresses to eth0 (enp1s0 on my machine).

I started with sudo ifconfig enp1s0 up, then assign the IP address with sudo ifconfig enp1s0

The machine doesn't give me any error codes, it accepts it, but then 'thinks' forever. I end having to force it to give up (after about 16 hours - I left it overnight). I've tried skipping that step and configuring the netmask and gateway IPs, but again it just continues 'loading' forever.

When I go into /etc/resolv.conf and /etc/network/interfaces, they're empty. I've tried configuring these files, it doesn't change the addresses when I run ip addr.

I've read the posts that said /etc/network/interfaces has moved to netplan, but the config file (/etc/netplan/config.yaml) is also empty. Adding the lines to that file also doesn't do anything. The only file that has anything in it is /etc/netplan/*yaml, the output is below. I tried changing the IP addresses and was somewhat successful, I told netplan to 'try' and it accepted the file, but timed out before I could press 'ok'. I tried to apply and again it thought about it for hours.

enp1s0:

accept-ra: true

dhcp4: true

dhcp6: true

match:

```
 macaddress: 56:00:04:64
```

set-name: enp1s0

I've tried adding the IP address with sudo ip addr add  dev enp1s0. But when I try to delete the old IP address, the machine 'thinks' for hours.

I really have no idea where to go next. Please help!